# How can I search specifically for cottages/cabins with kitchen(ettes)?

Tags: usa, accommodation

When searching for cabin/cottages on sites such as [HomeAway](http://www.homeaway.com/search/refined/california/big-sur/region:7165/Property+Type:barn/Property+Type:cabin/Property+Type:cottage/Property+Type:estate/Property+Type:house/Property+Type:lodge/arrival:2014-12-20/departure:2014-12-23/maxPrice/1500/currency/USD/minSleeps/2?view=m#) or [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/VRACSearch?inDay=20&outDay=23&geo=240329&token=c1ef5e336ff4ecedb3a352f1db30ca3e&adults=2&inMonth=12+2014&outMonth=12+2014), one can select many amenities, such as the presence of a sauna, hot tub, or air conditioning.  However, there does not appear to be an option to search for vacation accommodation with own kitchen(ette).

Is there any (reasonably complete) site to search for vacation accommodation based on (among other things) the ability to cook ones own food (i.e. fridge, freezer, and stove) — with either private or shared facilities?

*(I tagged this question [usa](/questions/tagged/usa) as that is where I am currently searching, but answers focussing on other locales are valuable as well)*

Comment: I would think that in the US any "cottage" or cabin would have a Kitchen(ette). Do you have reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: @Flimzy Most of the ones I've looked at in Big Sur make no mention of kitchen(ette)s but do advertise "breakfast included" and fine dining.  For example, [Lucia lodge](http://www.lucialodge.com/accommodations.html) has "10 updated cabins" with no kitchen facilities to be seen on any photo (but I've asked to be sure).  For [Riverside campground cabins](http://www.riversidecampground.com/Cabins.html), some cabins are advertised to have a kitchenette, implying the rest (that are cheaper) do not.  [Big Sur Camp](http://www.bigsurcamp.com/cabins.html) also has cabins both with and without.

Comment: hmm, maybe by "cabin" they mean more along the lines ... you'll have a kind of property where there are 10 or so "cabins" - not unlike motel rooms, but, in the "log cabin" style .. in the woods.  Sure enough, just like a motel, those would have no kitchen.  Note that **apartment rental**, "holiday apartment rental", always has a kitchen. on the site holidayrentals, I'd be very surprised if there is literally 1 property, on the whole site, with no kitchen (**it would be very clearly marked, as an exception, if so**)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the comments, I suppose this kind of filters depends on the audience of the website. HomeAway is oriented towards whole house rentals, so they would expect a kitchen comes along. However, like you, I would be glad to see that such websites have extensive filtering options for most people's needs. And they may be open to introduce more if you send them an email, or at least add a mention to the ads without any kitchen.

I looked a bit around and found a couple websites with such filters and covering a wide offer, including USA and international places.

[AirBnb](https://www.airbnb.com/s/Big-Sur--Monterey-County--CA--United-States?hosting_amenities%5B%5D=8&property_type_id%5B%5D=4) offers relatively many options (including kitchen and cabin) to filter the places you want to go to (even a First Aid Kit). Unlike HomeAway, I think AirBnb also targets those people wanting to rent a room and still being able to cook their own meals.

[Booking.com](http://www.booking.com) offers also many filters including kitchen and kitchenette (check either one). Booking.com targets a super-wide audience with hotels, bed and breakfast and cottages/cabins.

[Hostels.com](http://www.hostels.com) as well as [Hostelworld](http://www.hostelworld.com/) (same parent company, apparently same search results filtering) also have kitchen filters (and also a 'cooker' filter). Again the audience matters, since the hostels are also popular for the group atmosphere and cooking your own meal. These are rarely cottages or cabins, though.

[Couchsurfing](https://www.couchsurfing.com/) hosts would also be likely willing to share their kitchen, but again you will likely not be able to find a cottage.

### Conclusion

In the end it seems to vary from website to website. There are a couple listed above that offer filters on kitchens.